# Jmeter shows less latency time whereas Bombardier shows more

Tags: jmeter

Jmeter shows less latency time whereas Bombardier shows more .

Can any one explain what is resason behind .

What is pros and cons of bombardier tool response results.

Answer (score 1):

1. I'm getting the opposite picture for my measurement:

   [image]
2. You are comparing 2 different metrics, what is called ["Latency" in bombardier](https://github.com/codesenberg/bombardier/blob/master/bombardier.go#L228) it's [Elapsed Time](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) in JMeter
3. Be informed that bombardier can only "bombard" the static URL, it should be enough to do a baseline testing of i.e. an API endpoint, but it's not sufficient for the modern website where you need to [properly represent a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) in terms of:

   - handling embedded resources and [caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) them
   - [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) support
   - extracting data from responses and passing it to next request
   - etc.

Moreover [JMeter has much better reporting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)